# How to wrap a component and inherit its props interface

Tags: typescript, antd

I would like to extend a Button component and extend its props interface type, in order to accept and pass all props that the normal Button has. In the example below I created a button which receives a promise from it's onClick function, and displays the loader while waiting for it to resolve.

My problem seems to be that the compiler doesn't know where to find ButtonProps, and it is probably defined in its own namespace.

Can I somehow take that definition and extend it for my own component? I don't want to have to redefine props like "type", and just pass them through.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'antd';

// extend interface already defined in antd
interface ButtonProps {
  onClick: (event: any) => Promise<any>;
}

interface AsyncButtonState {
  loading: boolean;
}

export class AsyncButton extends React.Component<
  ButtonProps,
  AsyncButtonState
> {
  public state = {
    loading: false,
  };

  public render() {
    return (
      <Button
        {...this.props}
        onClick={this.handleClick}
        loading={this.state.loading}
      />
    );
  }

  private handleClick = async evt => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    await this.props.onClick(evt);
    this.setState({ loading: false });
  };
}

export default AsyncButton;
```

---- EDIT ----

I found a way to import the ButtonProps interface from antd. Now I only need to figure out how to extend it I think.

```
import { ButtonProps } from 'antd/lib/button';

interface ButtonProps {
  onClick: (event: any) => Promise<any>;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}
```

This gives an error for the import saying: "import declaration conflicts with local declaration of ButtonProps"

----- EDIT AGAIN ----

I used to solve this with

```
import { Button } from 'antd';
import { ButtonProps } from 'antd/lib/button';

interface AsyncButtonState {
  loading: boolean;
}

interface AsyncButtonProps extends ButtonProps {
  onClick: (event: any) => Promise<any>;
  foo?: string;
}
```

... but now it seems that ButtonProps is not exported as an interface anymore but a type. What now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that Antd props are exported as type this is seems to be way to solve it:

```
import { Button } from 'antd';
import { ButtonProps } from 'antd/lib/button';

interface AsyncButtonProps {
  onClick: (event: any) => Promise<any>;
  foo?: string;
}

export class AsyncButton extends React.Component<
  AsyncButtonProps & ButtonProps,
  AsyncButtonState
> {
  public render() {
    return (
      <Button
        {...this.props}
        onClick={this.handleClick}
        loading={this.state.loading}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It turned out to be quite easy after all.

```
import { Button } from 'antd';
import { ButtonProps } from 'antd/lib/button';

interface AsyncButtonState {
  loading: boolean;
}

interface AsyncButtonProps extends ButtonProps {
  onClick: (event: any) => Promise<any>;
  foo?: string;
}
```

The onClick handler returning a promise was already compatible with the current ButtonProps interface, so I think it is not required for me. But this shows adding another optional prop called `foo`.

Comment: ButtonProps is now exported as a type and not an interface anymore Does anyone know how to solve this now?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with typescript, would this work?

```
interface ButtonProps {
  onClick: (event: any) => Promise<any>;
  ...Button.propTypes
}
```

we do similar thing with es6 and works well

```
const propTypes = {
   something: PropTypes.string,
   ...Button.propTypes
}

MyButton.propTypes = propTypes;
```

Comment: Yes something similar should be possible with Typescript. I think interfaces are just merged (you don't need the spread). I found a way to import the button props interface for my own use (see edit), only I don't know how to make the compiler understand that I'm addressing an interface from the antd package instead of creating a new one. Maybe this is [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37263357/how-to-declare-and-import-typescript-interfaces-in-a-separate-file)