# how to import a interface in typescript

Tags: typescript

I define a interface in typescript `"typescript": "^4.5.5",` like this:

```
interface MessageType{ 
    type: String,
    data: any,
}
```

when I using this command to import the interface in Vue 3:

```
import type { MessageType } from "@/model/message/MessageType";
```

shows error like this:

```
ERROR in /Users/xxx/source/reddwarf/frontend/reddwarf-translate-plugin/src/public/widget/translator/Translator.vue.ts
3:33-62
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/xxx/source/reddwarf/frontend/reddwarf-translate-plugin/src/public/widget/translator/Translator.vue.ts(3,34)
      TS2306: File '/Users/xxx/source/reddwarf/frontend/reddwarf-translate-plugin/src/model/message/MessageType.ts' is not a module.
```

why did this happen? what should I do to import this interface?

Comment: Are you exporting the interface?

Comment: did you check it ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37263357/how-to-declare-and-import-typescript-interfaces-in-a-separate-file/60343829